# How can I insert a string into other certain strings that meet a criteria?

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently designing a program that takes user input, converts that (if in English) to Pig Latin and vice versa. When you click on the menu button or press F3, the conversion happens. This is what the specific block of code is currently:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To words.Length - 1
    If inputTextBox.Text Like "" Then
        'i = words(i).Insert(i, "--way")
            outputTextBox.Text = words(i)
    End If
Next
```

What I want to do is, if text inside meets criteria such as if input inside the input text box starts with a, e, i, o or u, that word should get a "--way" tagged on at the end. I got the vice versa part working by saying:

```
If inputTextBox.Text Like "--way" Then
        MsgBox("Cannot convert, already in English.")
End If
```

but I'm not sure how to code as to detect if there is NO "--way" anywhere.
Another conversion part is if a word does NOT begin with a, e, i, o or u but contains a, e, i, o, u or y WITHIN the word, those words get:

a dash (-) at the end of the word

the first letter of the word gets moved to the end of the word (this loops until the first letter is a, e, i, o, u or y)

the word gets an "ay" at the end

So Ted becomes "ed-tay."

To sum it all up, my questions are:

1 - How can I set up my Like command to add --way to specific words?

2 - How can I detect for words inside the text box that do NOT have --way in them?

Comment: Too bad there isnt a way for the [string class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) to report if a string ends with something or...starts with something or ...simply contains something or....maybe could give the the index of a sub string....darn the luck.  Also, 41,900 such posts here.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do everything but if you know the right way.

For detecting words in single strings you need to break(divide) the strings in part. In past 2 days, I had worked on this project.

You should first divide the String into columns(pieces), then read each and every word separately. For analysing a string use this sample. Although this method is long you can try other ways as well like you can use array or list. E.g:

```
`Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MyWord As String = TextBox1.Text   'This is the input string by user.
    Dim writer As New StreamWriter(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory + "/fp.txt") 'Filepath = for e.g. =  D:\Myfile.txt
    Dim i As Double = 0
    Dim MyWordlength As Double = MyWord.length
    Dim column As String
    While i < MyWordlength
        column = MyWord.Chars(i)
        writer.WriteLine(column)
        i = i + 1
    End While
    writer.close()
    writer.Dispose()
    ' Then set code to analyse
    Dim i2 As Double = 0
    Dim firstcharacter As String = ReadALine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory + "/fp.txt", GetNumberofLines(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory + "/fp.txt"), 0) 'Set File Path (any you wish but valid)
    'char.
    If firstcharacter = "a" Or firstcharacter = "A" Or firstcharacter = "e" Or firstcharacter = "E" Or firstcharacter = "i" Or firstcharacter = "I" Or firstcharacter = "o" Or firstcharacter = "O" Or firstcharacter = "U" Or firstcharacter = "u" Then
        MsgBox("Should not start with a,e,i,o,u.")
    End If
    'For analysing remaining words.
    Dim linec As String
    Dim check As Boolean = False
    While i2 <= MyWord.Length
        linec = ReadALine("D:\Myfile.txt", GetNumberofLines(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory + "/fp.txt"), i2)
        If linec <> "a" Or linec <> "i" Or linec <> "e" Or linec <> "o" Or linec <> "u" Or linec <> "A" Or linec <> "E" Or linec <> "I" Or linec <> "O" Or linec <> "U" Then
            check = False
            i2 = i2 + 1
        Else
            check = True
        End If
    End While
    If check = True Then
    Else
        MsgBox("You does'not use any vowel between all letters.")
    End If
End Sub
Public Function ReadALine(ByVal File_Path As String, ByVal TotalLine As Integer, ByVal Line2Read As Integer) As String
    Dim buffer As Array
    Dim line As String
    If TotalLine <= Line2Read Then
        Return "0"
    End If
    buffer = file.ReadAllLines(File_Path)
    line = buffer(Line2Read)
    Return line
End Function
Public Function GetNumberofLines(ByVal File_path As String) As Integer
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(File_path)
    Dim numberoflines As Integer
    Do While sr.Peek >= 0
        sr.ReadLine()
        numberoflines += 1
    Loop
    Return numberoflines
    sr.Close()
    sr.Dispose()
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: For any help don't hesitate.