# Visual Basic splitting a word into letters then find all vowels

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Visual Basic
I've been given an assignment for school where we are creating a "Circuit Breaker" Game. The idea is that '' Your program is to load and run three(3) to five(5) working puzzles and give the user the opportunity to play and check his or her entries.''
The player will be given a vowel with random letters and must find all  possible words that can be made, to win.

The easiest way I've found to do this is I'm using a textfile with a list of random words. Once the program starts a random word is chosen and the program checks all other words that can be made from the first word given. (If that makes sense?)

The area i need help with is breaking the chosen word up into letters then finding all vowels in the word. What would be the easiest way to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: Read the answer on this page. [Answer - Working with strings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50074549/9345155)

Comment: Remember, strings are just array of chars. You can examine each letter using the array notation. Try to produce a solution and then show your effort in your question. This is how, at minimum, to ask homework questions

Comment: @Steve, to be precise, a `String` is not actually an array of `Char` values. The `String` class does implement `IEnumerable(Of Char)` and it aslo has a default `Chars` property of type `Char`. When you index a `String`, you're actually getting that `Chars` property, much as indexing a collection is actually betting its `Items` property. It is much like an array in use but it's not actually an array. For one thing, the `Chars` property is `ReadOnly`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string as an array of chars. For example:

```
Dim word as String = "hello word";
```

word(0) = s

word(1) = t

if you want to find the vowels you can just fo a for

```
For i As Integer = 0 To word.count 
    If word(i) = 'a' Or word(i) = 'e' Then
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The question is tagged VB.NET so any answer should be provided in VB.NET. Otherwise, it's not actually an answer to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all words from a string using the below code :

```
  Dim testString as String = "my name is"
  Dim AllWords as String() = testStrng.Split(" ")
```

Now you can check for vowels :

```
 For each Word in AllWords 
  For each letter as Char in Word
   If letter = "a" Or letter = "e" or …….. Then
   'Your code here
   End if
  Next
 Next
```

Hope this helps you :)